# The LocationListener class doesn't have an onLocationChanged() method?

Tags: android

With this code:

```
private class WRYLocationListener implements LocationListener
//private class WRYLocationListener extends LocationListener <- I tried this, too, with the same results
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
. . .
```

I get this err msg:

The method onLocationChanged(Location) of type Activity.WRYLocationListener must override a superclass method.

I got this code from a book; "extends" makes more sense to me here than "implements" (maybe it's a typo in the book?), but even with "extends" I get the same err msg...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`implements` is the only thing that makes sense, because [`LocationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) is an interface.

The `@Override` annotation for interfaces, however, is a JDK 6 feature, not JDK 5, and should be removed. In JDK 5, `@Override` is valid *only* if a class overrides a superclass method (as opposed to implementing an interface method).

Comment: I'm using JDK7, actually, which has already caused me a little grief as far as generating the MD5 value for a Google Maps account (had to go back to the "days of antiquity" and download JDK6 to get it to work.SO, since it (@Override) is "kosher" in JDK6, one would _think_ it would be in JDK7, too, no?

Comment: @ClayShannon Hmm, yes, it's fine in JDK7, but you're compiling your Android stuff in JDK7? Is your IDE's compliance set to 1.5?

Comment: I don't know; how do you set that?

Comment: I don't know what IDE you're using. It should be somewhere in the project settings. Android projects should use 1.5 compliance.

Comment: It is set to 1.5. I'm using all the latest tooling for Eclipse, Java, JDK, Android downloads, Windows 7, you name it - everything was installed within the last week or so.